# Monitoring different values

Tags: android, monitoring

I'm working on an app which consists of several users with tablets and each user has associated some identifier. Is there a way of retrieving a list containing each user with the tablets identifier and those identifiers and the changes made to the identifiers in certain duration?

For example if there are 20 tablets running the application, the administrator could see those tablets showing also the username of the person running the app. Let's say is it possible to monitor this process while the users are running the app?

Comment: you should come out with server, and all devices running your app will send their connection status to the server with all information that you want.

Comment: look at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/.. they have free trial with all necessary infrastructure for you to get started

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you implement it yourself :

You will have to dev a [thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) in your application which send the informations at your administrator server from time to time

Then you update the informations when you close your application to notify the server the user isn't using it anymore